# Firebase get data by timestamp

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to filter data using to get specific data for the timestamp match.

For example I need the data where `arrivalTime` matches with exact date and time fields, timestamp field in database.

I am trying below but it returns no data.

```
  _arrivalTIme = moment(
            `${todaysDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD')} ${_arrivalTIme}:00`,
          ).toDate();

// _arrivalTIme: Thu May 28 2020 09:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)

return firestore()
  .collection('mainCol')
  .doc(todayDate)
  .collection('subCol')
  .where('arrivalTime', '==', `${_arrivalTIme}`) ...
```

my db record looks like this: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a date field in your database with a string from your code. That comparison will never be true.

You'll either need to get a `Timestamp` value that is exactly the same as the value in the database, or (more commonly) do a range check:

```
return firestore()
  .collection('mainCol')
  .doc(todayDate)
  .collection('subCol')
  .where('arrivalTime', '>=', new Date('2020-05-28 08:00:00')
  .where('arrivalTime', '<', new Date('2020-05-28 08:01:00')
```

Comment: your range check worked fine. I am figuring out how to use timestamp. I updated the question with _arrivalTIme format that I am passing

Comment: _arrivalTIme = moment(todaysDate).format(`YYYY-MM-DD ${_arrivalTIme}:00:00`) and new Date(_arrivalTIme) worked for '==' operator